# Verify mock invocation only in specific code block, igoring other calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have this (simplified) service class:

```
public interface EventListener {

    void call();
}

public class MyService {

    private final EventListener eventListener;

    private final List<String> elements = new LinkedList<>();

    public MyService(EventListener eventListener) {
        this.eventListener = eventListener;
    }

    public void addElement(String element) {
        elements.add(element);
        eventListener.call();
    }

    public void removeElement(String element) {
        elements.remove(element);
        eventListener.call();
    }
}
```

And this test method:

```
@Test
public void remove_should_call_event_listener() {
    // arrange
    EventListener eventListener = Mockito.mock(EventListener.class);
    MyService myService = new MyService(eventListener);
    myService.addElement("dummy");

    // act
    myService.removeElement("dummy");

    // assert
    Mockito.verify(eventListener).call();
}
```

How can I tell Mockito to ignore calls of `eventListener.call()` during "arrange" and verify only calls during "act"? I want to verify that `eventListener.call()` was called during `myService.removeElement(...)` and ignore all other calls.

Comment: You can put a verify in between. `myService.addElement(...); Mockito.verify(eventListener).call(); myService.removeElement(...); Mockito.verify(times(2), eventListener).call();`

Comment: Another option, if the real code has e.g. different arguments for the `.call()` invocation, could be to use an ArgumentCaptor: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before acting, call:

```
Mockito.reset(eventListener); // resets the set-up also
```

or

```
Mockito.clearInvocations(eventListener) // resets only the invocation history
```